# ifdef equivalent in TCL

Tags: bash, shell, tcl

In TCL, is there an elegant implementation that will mimic `ifdef frequently used in programming languages. From TCL scripting language itself, I couldn't find a way that is natively supported by TCL interpreter.

Comment: No, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Based on a particular project I may have to change the commands to a tool that supports TCL language in chip design. For eg, `ifdef PROJ_FOO set_lib x `else set_lib y `endif - This is the intent

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/

Comment: There isn't a separate compile time from run time, so there's no need for an `#ifdef`-alike. Just use `if` as @BryanOakley says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing built in to Tcl that is equivalent to "ifdef", except for the standard "if" statement. If you don't like the standard "if" statement, tcl gives you all of the fundamental building blocks to create your own "ifdef" command.

For example, ifdef is really nothing more than an if statement looking for a defined value. A really simple implementation might look something like this:

```
proc define {name value} {
    set ::defined($name) $value
}

proc ifdef {name script1 else script2} {
    if {[info exists ::defined($name)]} {
        uplevel $script1
    } else {
        uplevel $script2
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
define FOO 1
...
ifdef FOO {
    <do this if FOO is defined>
} else {
    <do this if FOO is NOT defined>
}
```

Comment: @Mike: I've updated my answer with an example. My tcl skills are pretty rusty, but this seems to work. For a more production-ready implementation you might need more bullet-proofing, and make the else block optional, but I hope it gives an idea.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's slic solution

Answer (score 4):

If you try to check an evironment variable, you can do something like:

```
if {[info exists ::env(PROJ_FOO)]} {
   set_lib x
} else {
   set_lib y
}
```

Assuming you have some Tcl command called `set_lib`.

Comment: set_lib is a tool specific command. Looks like the only way to go about it is setting a ENV variable, as in SHELL programming languages. I was thinking whether there is any command line option to selectively run the code. tcl -f foo.tcl -define PROJ_FOO (avoids setting ENV variable)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [info exists varName] and similar. For example:

if {![info exists myVar]} {puts "myVar is undefined so define it here"}

A little more typing but it is obvious what's happening and can be used for anything info can check for.